# Horizontal align center animated “X” icon in navbar-toggle (Bootstrap3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I using this example http://codepen.io/JulienMelissas/pen/LEBGLj for animate toogle button in navbar from Bootstrap, but `transform-origin` is not centered, I tried `transform-origin: 10% center;` but not work.

See example (the "X" not centralizes):

```css
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div style="width: 320px;"> <!--// Force show mobile menu -->


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Default</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
</nav>

</div> <!--// Force show mobile menu -->

<div style="height: 600px;"></div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In Firefox, Chrome and IE11:

> [image: no centered icon]

Expected result:

> [image: centered icon]

How do I adjust the `transform-origin` to center the "X"?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot? The 'X' looks centered to me.

Comment: @Dale in Chrome and Firefox on Windows 8 is not centered : http://i.stack.imgur.com/3G20N.png (I update question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `translate` to transform attribute. Like this

```
transform: translate(3px)rotate(45deg);
```

and

```
transform: translate(3px)rotate(-45deg);
```

translate comes before rotate because the order is important. first 3px to the right, then rotate.

Comment: **Tip:** In Safari/webkit iOS use `-webkit-transform: translate(3px) rotate(-45deg);`